# Probability for number of contained coins

Tags: probability

Here is a situation for a probability question

> Assume that you have a bag containing 10 coins. You know that there
>   may be either silver or gold coins in the bag, but you do not know how
>   many silver and gold coins there are.

Because the size is just 10, I figured I can work out all the possible cases so I can understand to answer the questions that follow. Representing the number of silver and gold coins as tuples, I think only the following configurations are possible:

(0,10), (1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5), (6,4), (7,3), (8,2), (9,1), (10,0)

They amount to a total of 11 configurations. If I had to derive this number logically without having to count all configurations, I can say I just need to choose the number for either silver or gold coins and there are 11 ways of choosing them(0 through 10, all inclusive). After the first number is chosen, second number is 10 less the first number.

The first question is

> What is the initial probability p(nS) that the bag contains nS silver
>   coins?

I note that the question asks about the probability that the bags `contains` n silver coins. Given that eleven possibilities exist, I would define the probability that the bag contains n silver coins as

$$P(n) = \begin{cases}
1/11,  & \text{if 0 $\le$ $n$ $\le$ 10} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

This is true also for the gold coins.

The second question is

> You pull out one coin: it is silver. What is now the probability that
>   the bag contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 silver coins?

Given that the `pulled` out coin is silver, it is possible only in 10 of the 11 combinations. The combination it is not possible in is (0,10) where all coins are gold. I would define the probability of the above question as

$$P(n) = \begin{cases}
1/10,  & \text{if 0 $\le$ $n$ $\le$ 9} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

The last question is

> You now pull out another coin: it is gold. What is now the
>   probability that the bag contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 silver
>   coins?

So, we pulled out two coins in total and one of them is silver and other is gold. This case is possible only in 9 of the 11 total possible combinations. The combinations where this is not possible are when all the coins are silver(10,0) or all the coins are gold(0,10). Accordingly, I would define the probability of the above question as

$$P(n) = \begin{cases}
1/9,  & \text{if 0 $\le$ $n$ $\le$ 8} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

My first obvious question is if my approach towards these questions is correct?

If no, what is the flaw in my logic?

If yes, how would I derive this using conditional probability techniques or Bayes theorem because it might not be possible to enumerate so easily for larger combinations/numbers?

Comment: Even if we assume a uniform prior, the conditional distribution of the number of blacks remaining, **given** that the ball we pulled out was black, is not uniform on the set $0$ to $9$. Do a $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$ calculation.

Comment: This depends a _lot_ on how the bag was filled with balls. What you're describing is if whoever filled the bag threw an eleven-sided die (numbered $0$ to $10$), filled the bag with the corresponding number of white balls and then topped it off with black balls. Another common interpretation is that whoever filled the bag had a _huge_ container filled with billions of balls, exactly the same amount of black and white. Then he filled the bag by blindly reaching down and picking up ten balls. In this case the probability of five-five is a _lot_ higher than the probability of all white.

Comment: In other words, the first question is meaningless. If the problem statement provides no prior distribution for the number of black balls, your assumption that all numbers are equally likely is as good or bad as any other assumption.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you please explain it in a bit more detail? In your equation does event B represent the case where the pulled out ball was black? Does A represent the event that we pull out 0-9 black balls? I've done basic probability before, but conditional probability seems quite confusing to me.

Comment: @Arthur My understanding is that we already have a bag with 10 balls in it, but we do not know how many are white or black. We want to find out the probabilities of the events in question. I was trying to enumerate what combinations exist for the state the bag is in and count from there. Does that make any sense?

Comment: The event $B$ is the event we pick out a black ball. The **events** $A_k$ are the events there are $k$ black balls left, $k=0$ to $9$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! Making a notation makes it quite clear. Following that logic, I figured $$P(A_k)=1/11$$, $$P(B)=1/2$$ and $$P(B|A_k)=k/10$$. Applying $$P(A_k|B) = \frac{P(B|A_k).P(A_k)}{P(B)}$$, $$P(A_k|B)$$ works out to $$k/55$$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @joriki Just to understand the concept, if we assume that my first assumption is good, does the reasoning for the remaining part check out?

Comment: @Sundeep: On the assumption of a uniform prior, your calculation is correct, **in outline**. However, the probability of $B$, given $A_k$, is $\frac{k+1}{10}$, $k=0$ to $9$. That changes the final answer a little.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Assuming k is 2, there are 2 black balls and 8 white balls. So, the probability that we pick a black ball in this case would be 2/10, no? So, it is k/10. I don't understand how it can be k+1/10. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the notation I used, $k$ is the number of black balls **left**, so in your example $k=1$.  So if $Y$ is the number of blacks in "the rest", then $Y$ has distribution given by $\Pr(Y=k)=\frac{k+1}{55}$, $k=0$ to $9$.

Comment: @Sundeep: I avoid chat. If you intended your $\frac{k}{55}$ to apply for $k=0$ to $9$, note that the sum is not $1$.  Or else note that $k/55$ is clearly false for $k=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You are correct. I have written it down clearly and arrived at $\frac{k+1}{55}$. However, my other doubt is that we said $P(A_k)$ is 1/11. However, if the first ball is black, doesn't it mean that the combination where all balls are white is no longer in question and $P(A_k)$ is 1/10 instead? That puts $P(B|A_k)$ at $\frac{k+1}{50}$? I appreciate your patience with me. Thank you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas On second thought, $\frac{k+1}{50}$ doesn't add up to 1 while $\frac{k+1}{55}$ does. I'll give this some more thought.

Comment: The event $A_k$ is there are $k$ black left after a black is taken out. So $A_k$ says there were initially $k+1$ black. Under our assumption of a uniform prior, all initial numbers of blacks from $0$ to $10$ are equally likely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Excellent. For the second question, I'm arriving at the answer $\frac{16k+18-2k^2}{495}$, for $0 \le k \le 8$but it doesn't add up to 1. If event C is picking a black ball followed by a white ball, I arrived at $P(C|A_k) = \frac{k+1}{10}*\frac{9-k}{9}$ and $P(C) = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. Can you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: I did a quick calculation, the probability of your $C$, which I assume means the event drew a black then a white, is $\frac{1}{6}$, not $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wow. Now that makes $P(A_k|C) = \frac{8k+9-k^2}{165}$ adding up to 1 when summed for k from 0 to 8. But, now I'm confused why the probability is 1/6? I arrived at 1/4, by multiplying probability of drawing a black(1/2) and probability of drawing a white(1/2) and if we think of 0 as a black ball and 1 as a white ball, then for pulling out two balls, the possibilities are 00,01,10, 11 of which we want 01, thus 1/4. But clearly, my logic is wrong. How is it 1/6?

Comment: Informally, if we pull out a black that is some indication that the initial distribution was tilted towards black, so the probability of black then white is less than $(1/2)(1/2)$. Formally, I computed the crude way, taking all possible cases and adding up. Got $(1/11)(165/90)$, which simplifies. There may be a cleverer way. You should consider writing up an answer, since now you pretty much know what's going on.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I cannot thank you enough for the help you provided. Thank you. I added an answer now.

Comment: @Sundeep: You are welcome. Nice outcome, since you wrote a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is correct.

> What is the initial probability p(nS) that the bag contains nS silver coins?

$$P(nS) = 1/11 $$

Now, the second question

> You pull out one coin: it is silver. What is now the probability that the bag contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 silver coins?

The analysis in the question is wrong because the question is about conditional probability. We want to find out the probability of the event that the bag contains n silver coins($0 \le n \le 9$), **given** that the first coin pulled out was a silver coin. We will use Bayes' theorem to solve this.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4rlJ82CUZI) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh1E8cGoV7k) for Bayes theorem and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2tNxIaGpR4) for an illustrative example. The idea of drawing all the probabilities as a tree demonstrated in this idea is quite helpful in understanding the problem. Now, solution to the problem.

Lets us call the event we pulled out one silver coin as $O$.

Let us call the event there are n silver coins remaining in the bag as $nS$, where $0 \le n \le 9$

We want to find out $P(nS | O)$

Using Bayes formula

$$P(nS|O) = \frac{P(O|nS). P(nS)}{P(O)}$$

From the above question, we know that

$$P(nS) = 1/11 $$

$P(O|nS)$ is defined as the probability where a silver coin is picked given there are n silver coins remaining in the bag after the ball is picked. Since there are n silver coins remaining after the first silver coin was picked, the probability $P(O|nS)$ can be defined as $\frac{n+1}{10}$

$$P(O|nS) = \frac{n+1}{10}$$

$P(O)$ is the probability that a silver coin is picked from the bag on the first turn. Since there are either silver or gold coins in the bag, there is equal probability for both. Thus,

$$P(O) = 1/2$$

This can also be derived by drawing the tree as illustrated in the video

$$P(O) = (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{0}{10}) + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{1}{10}) + .... + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{9}{10}) + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{10}{10})$$

$$P(O) = \frac{1}{11}(\frac{0}{10} + \frac{1}{10} + .... + \frac{9}{10} + \frac{10}{10})$$

$$P(O) = \frac{1}{11}(\frac{0+1+2+ ... + 9 + 10}{10}) = \frac{55}{11*10} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Substituting these values in

$$P(nS|O) = \frac{P(O|nS). P(nS)}{P(O)}$$

> $$P(nS|O) = \frac{n+1}{55}$$

---

> You now pull out another coin: it is gold. What is now the probability that the bag contains 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 silver coins?

Let us call the event where two coins were pulled, and the first one is silver and other is gold as $T$.

Let us call the event there are n silver coins remaining in the bag as $nS$, where $0 \le n \le 8$

We want to find out $P(nS | T)$

Using Bayes formula

$$P(nS|T) = \frac{P(T|nS). P(nS)}{P(T)}$$

We know that

$$P(nS) = 1/11 $$

$P(T|nS)$ is defined as the probability where a silver coin is drawn first and gold coin is drawn next given there are n silver coins remaining in the bag after the two coins are picked. On the first turn, the probability for a silver coin to be picked is $\frac{n+1}{10}$. In the second turn, 9 coins would be left in the bag and n of them are silver coins, so, there would be $9-n$ gold coins. The probability of picking a gold coin in the second turn would be $\frac{9-n}{9}$. Combined, the probability would be

$$P(T|nS) = \frac{n+1}{10}*\frac{9-n}{9}$$

$P(T)$ is the probability that a black ball is picked from the bag first followed by a white ball. This can be derived from the probability tree

$$P(T) = (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{0}{10}) + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{1}{10}*\frac{9}{9}) + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{2}{10}*\frac{8}{9}) .... + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{9}{10}*\frac{1}{9}) + (\frac{1}{11}*\frac{10}{10}*\frac{0}{9})$$

$$P(T) = \frac{1}{11}(\sum_{n=0}^{10} \frac{n(10-n)}{10*9})$$

$$P(T) = \frac{1}{11}(\frac{165}{90}) = \frac{1}{6}$$

Substituting these values in

$$P(nS|T) = \frac{P(T|nS). P(nS)}{P(T)}$$

> $$P(nS|T) = \frac{8n+9-n^2}{165}$$